# Is it good pratice to add closure inside constructor?

Tags: php, closures

I have added closure inside the constructor and unsure of its performance as well as best practice. What is the best way to do that if it is not the right way to do it?

```
<?php


class Foo
{
    private $operation;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->operation = [
            "==" => function($a,$b) {return $a == $b;}
        ];
    }
    public function processComparision($operand1,$operator,$operand2){
        if($operator == "=="){
            $func = $this->operation[$operator];
            return $func($operand1,$operand2);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: These are closures https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php

Comment: @GetSet If not Closure, is it a Lamda function?

Comment: @AshishKafle you may call them anon-functions or closures: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: @Progrock Is the above code is the right way to do it?

Comment: @AshishKafle as you can't add the anonymous function to your property declaration, moving to the constructor is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an [own array class](https://github.com/jspit-de/tableArray/blob/master/tableArray.php) with a lot of functions (or closures) defined in the constructor. This type of definition of functions also allows you to add your own functions with a method.

```
  public function addSqlFunction($name, $function){
    $this->userFct[$name] = $function;
    return $this;
  }
```

I only see advantages in doing this. I'm also happy with the speed. It is therefore "best practice" for me.

Comment: Yeah I think its a right way to do as well